# Hive Query Searching Partition which doent exists

Tags: hive

I have one partitioned table in which I have one partition 1.e.030220. I want to insert this data into another table using insert/select before inserting data I'm Just selecting my data in that table and writing below  query i.e.

```
    SELECT  col1,col2....partition_column(date1) FROM  table_name;
```

but I'm getting error like ../user/hive/warehouse/...dbname.db/tablename/date1=040220 file doesn't exists.
I'm not sure why is searching that partition which is not available in my table. Can someone please suggest me what is wrong here.?

Comment: Have you ever created 040220 partition and later deleted it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you have created 040220 partition earlier and later deleted it. In that scenario, run below query to repair your table.

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```